# Wake on LAN not working on Dell Windows 11 Desktop Computer

Tags: windows-11, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to get my PC to wake up from shutdown, wirelessly on my home network and if possible from outside the home.

My Set up is: Dell 5680 Gaming Desktop PC, Qualcomm QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter, Windows 11, Dell Home hub 4000 Wireless Router (connected to PC through WIFI only).

I've tried the following steps:

1. Enabled Wake up by Integrated LAN/WLAN in my BIOS Power settings
2. Enabled "Allow this device to wake the computer" and "Only Allow a Magic Packet to Wake the Computer" in my QCA9377 Wireless Adapter Properties.
3. I have disabled Fast startup, Sleep and Hibernation in Windows Power Settings and disabled Deep Sleep control for S4 and S5 in the BIOS settings.

I've tried multiple apps to wake up the computer while on the same network from my android phone: Moonlight, Wake On LAN and AnyDesk. Each attempt to wake up the computer from shutdown does nothing. However, I am able to wake the computer from sleep and hibernate when I'm on the same network if I enable them.

I've been following this guide: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/turn-on-computer-from-across-the-house-with-wake-on-lan

Is there any additional settings or steps I am missing to get WoL to work from a shutdown and/or an external network?

Thank you,

Serpent

Comment: Does your Dell system documentation say it supports Wake-on-WLAN **from shutdown**? Traditionally, shutdown means all power is completely off; no NICs or WNICs are getting any power to keep their network connection alive. Some servers and enterprise-class systems might be architected to have "Lights-Out Management" (LOM) features where "shutdown" doesn't truly mean shutdown, and the motherboard still provides power to certain chips (NICs and WNICs). But I wouldn't expect that of a product sold as a gaming system.

Comment: In my experience for wired Ethernet connections even when the workstation is fully powered off, you have to configure the Dell workstation BIOS to have these settings set... "DeepSleepCtrl" needs to be `Disabled`, "BlockSleep" needs to be `Disabled`, and "WakeOnLan" needs to be set to `LanOnly`. You also need to ensure UDP ports `7` and/or `9` can broadcast to the entire subnet and specify the machine's mac address, and then it will wake up. Using hibernate, sleep and all that mess causes issues, fully power down the machine without anything special with all that, and WOL just work with Dells.

Comment: If you are traversing routers and subnets, you might need to configure it to send those UDP broadcast packets across the subnets. It might be called `IPHelper` perhaps if you need to google something with your network devices.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly out of luck. Devices that do support Wireless Wake-on-LAN only support wake from system sleep states S3 (sleep) or S4 (hibernate) per [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000027615/intel-nuc.html). It just takes too much power to keep a wireless adapter connected while the computer is fully shut off.

Your options are generally going to be: Connect to your router using ethernet, or avoid fully shutting down the PC by re-enabling sleep/hibernate.